# Login to ASPX page with Perl script

Tags: asp.net, perl, web-scraping, mechanize, scrape

I am trying to scrap an ASPX page with Perl's [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) . The problem is that the page I want to scrape can be accessed only after logging in. I tried using the [HTML::TreeBuilderX::ASP_NET](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilderX%3a%3aASP_NET) module but can't seem to get it to work.

I tried setting the `__VIEWSTATE`, `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` parameters.

Does anybody have any experience in logging into ASPX page using a Perl script?

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you have to post the form (you'll only find one, typically, on any given aspx page; the form I'm talking about is the one found on login page) with all input values, including those hidden fields (especially those hidden fields, actually). the only values that you should change are uid/pwd textboxes. So, get the list of all named input tags, post them all; that should return a redirect with a asp.net auth cookie, which you have to include in subsequent requests.

Comment: +1 for (especially those hidden fields).  The fields are absolutely mandatory.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Brad, you need to return __VIEWSTATE as it is found in server's responses. Always, w/o exception. asp.net is using those to maintain state of controls on the page. , __EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT are set by javascript that executes _DoPostback. Actually, what you need to do is exactly what the login-button's onclick is doing: sets some hidden input fields, submits the form.